# how to create notification box like facebook in MVC4 in my web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub

every time I reload this page new connection get started and when i update data base data  notifications.client.updateNotifications = function () {
            alert("3");
            getAllNotifications()};

is called multiple times. otherwise it works fine

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var ConnectionStarted = false;
    $(function () {
        alert("1");
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateNotifications = function () {
            alert("3");
            getAllNotifications()

        };



        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            ConnectionStarted = true;

            alert("2");
            alert("connection started")
            getAllNotifications();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });

    });


    function getAllNotifications() {

        var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetNotifications',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
</script>
```